# How to Capture Exception Source Line in C# Code Coverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, testing, mstest

Wondering, how do I get code coverage to show for lines where I throw exceptions? I am using MS Test with the code coverage from the Visual Studio 2012 menu (i.e. menu Test\Analyze Code Coverage). The exceptions are occurring purposely for some tests.

For example, this line which ends up throwing an exception will not be marked as being executed for the purposes of code coverage

```
Errors.Instance.ThrowExceptionOnErrorIfEnabled(6);// index beyond bounds
```

The test method is marked with

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ApplicationException))]
```

Any help is appreciated. Perhaps, I missed it, but did not see a solution yet on StackOverflow. If more information is needed, just let me know. Thanks.